# docsify: out of multiple scripts only one script works on a single page

Tags: docsify

I am very new to javascript and docsify. I have the following scripts that work fine on a simple html page, but when I use docsify to generate them as a page only one of the script shows the graph. This is true for bunch of different pages I generated with several graphs using vegaEmbed.

```
<div id="script_1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunrock/io/master/plots/gunrock_primitives_tc_avg_process_time.json";
  vegaEmbed('#script_1', spec).then(function(result) {
    // Access the Vega view instance (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) as result.view
  }).catch(console.error);
</script>

<div id="script_2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spec = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunrock/io/master/plots/gunrock_primitives_tc_edges.json";
  vegaEmbed('#script_2', spec).then(function(result) {
    // Access the Vega view instance (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) as result.view
  }).catch(console.error);
</script>
```

You can find the page here: https://gunrock.github.io/docs/#/analysis/results_tc

I am including the following:

```
<!-- Vega and Vega-Lite Includes -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, only the first script tag is executed: https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=executescript